# Find the number of Invertible Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given square matrix $A_{k\times k}$ with  $k\geq4$. The entry of the
>   matrix $A$ is $1, 2, \ldots, k^2$ and let $n(A)$ is the number of
>   invertible matrix $A$. Find infimum of $n(A)$.

First, if $k$ increase, we must show that infimum $n(A)$ will increase. So infimum of $n(A)$ will attain when $k=4$.

How we compute the number of this Invertible matrix? Is compute the number of matrix with rank 2 or 3 necessary?

Comment: what exactly is 'number of a matrix'

Comment: In how many way we can create matrix A such that A invertible with entry A is 1, 2, ..., k^2 and all entries are different?

Comment: So the numbers from $1$ to $k^2$ are assigned exactly once to some matrix element of $A$?

Comment: Yes, so for k=4, the entry of A are 1, 2, ..., 16 with there's no repeating entry